# How to create a matrix with time in columns and date in rows for a long time-data frame?

Tags: r, time-series, reshape

I'm new here so...
I have a data frame with two variables (R is new for me, I used Matlab for a long). One is a classic POSIXlt with timestamps with 30 minutes between each data point. The second one is the data itself (for example, Air Temperature data) and same dimensions with time vector. I used this pair to get nice plots.
I want to reshape data using time in this fashion: I want to sort the data using days in the row-direction and time (up to 48 columns, using the 30-minute interval between 0:00 and 23:30) in the column-direction, to use this data in another R package to fill missing data.

```
>> head(data_f, 10)
                  time  data
1  2013-08-01 00:30:00 8.001
2  2013-08-01 01:00:00 7.918
3  2013-08-01 01:30:00 7.621
4  2013-08-01 02:00:00 7.564
5  2013-08-01 02:30:00 7.718
6  2013-08-01 03:00:00 7.846
7  2013-08-01 03:30:00 7.481
8  2013-08-01 04:00:00 7.351
9  2013-08-01 04:30:00 7.275
10 2013-08-01 05:00:00 7.291
```

More data

```
48 2013-08-02 00:00:00  9.372
49 2013-08-02 00:30:00  9.485
50 2013-08-02 01:00:00  9.151
51 2013-08-02 01:30:00  8.870
52 2013-08-02 02:00:00  8.504
53 2013-08-02 02:30:00  8.404
54 2013-08-02 03:00:00  8.342
55 2013-08-02 03:30:00  8.278
56 2013-08-02 04:00:00  8.229
57 2013-08-02 04:30:00  8.163
58 2013-08-02 05:00:00  8.092
59 2013-08-02 05:30:00  8.038
```

I want an ideally rectangular output (could be a matrix instead of a data frame), putting NAs where is no data available for that time. Something like this:

```
           (30-min span in this direction -->)
2013-08-01   NA  8.001 7.918 7.621 7.564 7.718 7.846 7.481 7.351 7.275 7.291 ...
2013-08-02 9.372 9.485 9.151 8.870 8.504 8.404 8.342 8.278 8.229 8.092 8.038 ...
2013-08-03   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ... ...
2013-08-04   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ... ...
...
...
```

I have worked porting a Matlab function (wrote for myself) to accomplish that but with no success, by the way R interprets date and time.

Update: How to generate data. (Consider that original data is from a 7-yr database from my work)

```
library(lubridate)

data_f = data.frame(time = seq(from = as_datetime("2013-08-01 00:30:00"),
                               to = as_datetime("2013-10-12 18:00:00"),
                               by = "30 min"), 
                               data = runif(3491, 2, 14))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please provide the code to generate the dataframe

Comment: Hi, this is from a 7-yr database from my work. A typical test case without using the data is: `require(lubridate)` and then using `data_f = data.frame(time = seq(from = as_datetime("2013-08-01 00:30:00"), to = as_datetime("2013-10-12 18:00:00"), by = "30 min", data = runif(3491, 2, 14)))`

Comment: It's better if you add the code in your question instead here in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could follow is separating date and time an then reshaping the data. Here the code with `tidyverse` functions:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(time = structure(c(1375317000, 1375318800, 1375320600, 
1375322400, 1375324200, 1375326000, 1375327800, 1375329600, 1375331400, 
1375333200, 1375401600, 1375403400, 1375405200, 1375407000, 1375408800, 
1375410600, 1375412400, 1375414200, 1375416000, 1375417800, 1375419600, 
1375421400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), 
    data = c(8.001, 7.918, 7.621, 7.564, 7.718, 7.846, 7.481, 
    7.351, 7.275, 7.291, 9.372, 9.485, 9.151, 8.87, 8.504, 8.404, 
    8.342, 8.278, 8.229, 8.163, 8.092, 8.038)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-22L))
```

Code:

```
#Split and reshape
df %>% separate(time,into = c('V1','V2'),sep = ' ') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = V2,values_from=data)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 13
  V1    `00:30:00` `00:59:59` `01:30:00` `02:00:00` `02:29:59` `03:00:00` `03:30:00` `03:59:59` `04:30:00`
  <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 2013~       8.00       7.92       7.62       7.56       7.72       7.85       7.48       7.35       7.28
2 2013~       9.48       9.15       8.87       8.50       8.40       8.34       8.28       8.23       8.16
# ... with 3 more variables: `05:00:00` <dbl>, `00:00:00` <dbl>, `05:29:59` <dbl>
```

As names of new variables can change you could rearrange them.